# Lambda expression in Iterable implementation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, iterable, shadowing

So I have this piece of code my friend showed me and I must admit I do not understand what is going on. I understand the concept around lamba expressions and have written quite a few of them in haskell but none in Java so far.

What confuses me is how does the compiler know that the function which I supposed is lambdaed is supposed to be the "iterator()" one required in the Iterable interface.

```
public Iterable<V> values() {
    return () -> {
        return new Iterator<V>() {
            private Iterator<TableEntry<K, V>> iter = iterator();

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return iter.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public V next() {
                return iter.next().getValue();
            }
        };
    };
}
```

I have my version of this but I have a problem with shadowing where the iterator() I make to implement Iterable for values is called inside itself causing stack overflow. What I want is to use the iterator() which is defined in the scope of the values() but don't know how to point to it.

```
public Iterable<V> values() {
    return new ValuesIterable<V>();
}

public class ValuesIterable<V> implements Iterable<V>{
    public Iterator<V> iterator() {
        return new ValuesIterator();
    }

    public class ValuesIterator implements Iterator<V>
    {
        Iterator<SimpleHashtable.TableEntry<K, V>> iter = (Iterator<TableEntry<K, V>>) iterator();

        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return iter.hasNext();
        }

        public V next()
        {
            return iter.next().getValue();
        }

        public void remove()
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

note: this iterator() is in the scope of variables()

```
public Iterator<SimpleHashtable.TableEntry<K, V>> iterator() {
    return new TableEntryIterator();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lambda expressions are used to implement functional interfaces, in which there is only one method that requires implementation. Therefore, since your `values()` method returns `Iterable<V>`, the lambda expression must implement the single method of that interface, which is `iterator()`.

As for the syntax of the lambda expression in your example :

The empty brackets `()` mean that the method implemented by the lambda expression has no arguments, which is indeed true for the `iterator()` method.

After the `->`, you have the body of the lambda expression, which in this example returns an instance of an anonymous class that implements the `Iterator<V>` interface.

Oh, and your second code snippet causes stack overflow because your `iterator()` method creates an instance of `ValuesIterator`, and as part of the initialization of the instance, you call that `iterator()` method, causing an infinite recursion.

Comment: Could you clarify the syntax behind this specific usage?

Comment: Thank you for this short and complete answer :)

Comment: _"which in this example returns an instance of an anonymous class"_ This is misleading. The compiler is unlikely to generate an anonymous class in the traditional sense. Generally, lambdas give Java developers access to [invokedynamic](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html).

Comment: @McDowell While that's true for lambda expressions, the body of the lambda expression in the question explicitly creates an anonymous class instance - `new Iterator<V>() {...`

Comment: @Eran Ah, my mistake, I misread your answer. You are correct.